# Importing "google-play-services_lib" into Eclipse crashes libgdx project

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, google-play-services

I am trying to add google ad banners for my libgdx android game. After following the guide https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-(replaces-deprecated-AdMob) and importing "google-play-services_lib" the game can't be started anymore. I am using Eclipse Luna. Eclipse  keeps loading until death.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the proper import do it this way:

**File -> Import -> Existing Android Project -> Browse the "google-play-services_lib" folder then make sure you have checked the "Copy project into workspace" box.**

After you have imported the google-play-services_lib:

**Right click to your project -> Properties -> Android , and then the bottom add the google-play-services_lib to your project.**

This tutorial helped me with implementing the ads: **http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/integrating-new-google-admob-banner-interstitial-ads/**

Comment: okay thank you i have followed your instructions and changed from eclipse luna to the ADT bundle eclipse. Works now!