# Android libGDX: Eclipse crash when using google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, admob, google-play-services

I'm learning how to make games in libGDX, and I'm trying to add ads to my game.

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwAN4LMXo58
(I'm using Eclipse instead of Android Studio).

I got stuck at 9:35 of the tutorial; I've copied all the code and everything seems to look good; **but when I try to run the code, nothing starts; Eclipse just keeps loading until the following error pops up:**

> Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
>
> GC overhead limit exceeded

It seems to be the same problem as this guy had:

[Importing "google-play-services_lib" into Eclipse crashes libgdx project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237569/importing-google-play-services-lib-into-eclipse-crashes-libgdx-project)

But I followed all the suggested steps and Eclipse still crashes... (I seem to have too little reputation to comment on that post).

---

Eclipse didn't crash before, when I didn't select *google-play-services_lib* in **Properties - Android** (after right-clicking the android project), but had it selected in **Properties - Java Build Path** ; but then there was a different problem (which I've partly forgotten), I believe the class AdView couldn't be found or something (sorry for not being to able to be specific).

I'm using Eclipse Luna. I've tried to make a new project just to try everything a second time; same problem.

---

**Please tell me if it would help to post other information! :)**

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to your VM options which you can change in your Eclipse.ini file. I don't know your default values but if you increase -Xms and Xmx limits, your problem will be fixed.

```
...
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
...
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; it worked, thanks a lot! :)